# Doctrine2 OneToMany Unidirectional Mapping Still Not Supported?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I saw old reference (3 years ago) to OneToMany Unidirectional (foreign key) not being implemented:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/y8du6cafhdA/QnY_h8NjD10J

I don't see it in current documentation and have also tried using JPA 2.0 onetomany unidirectional annotations and they don't work on Doctrine 2.3.3.

So can I assume OneToMany Unidirectional is still not implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneToMany Unidirectional is still not implemented as of Doctrine 2.3.3. I base this on the following response from Doctrine User Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/rXLvbhbBXj0